# System Design - how to Pick CPU, Memory for an application

Tags: kubernetes, memory-management, architecture, cpu-architecture, system-design

I am practicing System Design concepts and I am not clear what configuration (cpu, memory, disk storage) to pick for an application instance? Also, how many instances are needed (assuming you are running your application on Kubernetes cluster)

For Back of the envelope calculation ,I saw examples of calculating tps for read and write calls, calculate bandwidth needs, database storage needs etc. but I have not seen how to determine cpu, memory needs and how many instances are enough. Is there a procedure that guides to solve this problem?

My hunch says that we pick small to medium sized server instance (if we use cloud provider like AWS) and run stress tests for calculated TPS and see CPU and memory usage and see if we need to increase or decrease server configuration based on results?

I would greatly appreciate any inputs you may have.

Comment: This seems like a question for https://serverfault.com/.  It's not directly about programming, per-se, rather about provisioning / planning and logistics.  With maybe some performance estimation for totally unspecified application code.  There's only a vote-to-close option for it, not vote-to-migrate, and I'm not *sure* it would be on topic on on serverfault (since I don't hang around on that site much), so I'm not raising a custom flag to ask a mod to migrate.  If someone else agrees with my assessment, though, either flag yourself or reply to this and I will.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not clear what configuration (cpu, memory, disk storage) to pick for an application instance? Also, how many instances are needed (assuming you are running your application on Kubernetes cluster)

This is mostly a question about economics. If resources was very cheap, you could use a lot of them - but unfortunately, they have an economic cost.

### Scale out horizontal or scale up vertical

The first fundamental question to ask, should you scale up your app vertically (e.g. to bigger instances) or should you scale out your app horizontally.

The most important thing here is that **scaling out horizontally is much easier**. But wether you can scale out horizontally of if you have to scale up vertically depends on your app. If your app is a stateless webserver, it typically is very easy to scale out, but if you have a stateful cache or database, scale up vertically might be your only *short term option*. Try to design so that you can *scale out horizontally* since that is much easier.

### Accurate size - use observability

To find your accurate size, use observability and investigate your bottlenecks and adjust relatively to that.

E.g. if you use too little memory, your app will be terminated, or if you use too little CPU, your response time will be slow. Just start somewhere and adjust.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jonas's answer:

You have two approaches (which are not mutually exclusive):

1. Estimate your needs based on expected load, etc.
2. Adjust you needs based on what you observe in production.

**Regarding the first approach:**

1. Have you done any analysis into what your expected load is?  E.g. how many users (unique sessions), how many requests on average per hour (page views, API calls, etc), potential peaks in activity leading to increased load, etc.
2. Have you done any benchmarking?
3. Have you looked at your system and what it does, and worked out if it has any specific resource (CPU, memory, disk, etc) needs?

Estimating resources ahead of time requires some knowledge (or informed guesses) regarding what the load will be, as per the 3 points above.  Having an idea of what the daily or hourly request average is isn't a bad place to start.

Also make sure you aware if any potential spikes that might catch you out (end of month for financial systems/services).  Whether or not these are significant enough that is worth worrying about is another thing.  A friend of mine was working on a ticketing system once, and they had massive traffic spikes for major events that did warrant serious scaling-out and back... but your average system probably won't need to be that extreme.

CPU is probably only worth "worrying" about if you have anything that does any above average processing - this should be obvious through benchmarking or if you/your team has good knowledge of your code.

Disk usage can be calculated - e.g.

- If on average a user generates 1Mb of data in a session (not including system logs), and you get 100 sessions a day then that's 100Mb a day, 500Mb a working week, 200Mb a month, etc.
- If a user profile has on average 200Kb of data and 300Kb of storage space (images) then you can calculate that.
- You can also do this for records, especially for records that you know are "large" (e.g. >25mb) or where there will be lots of them (e.g. millions).

You can also start to forecast growth over time if you allow a growth rate (e.g. number of users and their sessions, and the amount of data generated).  A simple way to do that is to have a spreadsheet with some simple formulas that take various inputs like number of users, average requests per user, disk space per user, etc.  You can then do what-if modelling by playing with the inputs.

**In terms of the second approach** - as Jonas says, observe and adjust.  Make sure you know how to do that, and that your solution provides the data you need.  This might be using metrics provided by your cloud-provider (if applicable) or instrumentation / reporting you have custom built into you solution.

Scaling-Up is probably more relevant in scenarios where you have a central point/resource that cannot be scaled-out, like a central database.